# User B in User A's group, cant traverse dir that belongs to group A

Tags: permissions

Say I have 2 users: `user_a`, `user_b`, with home dirs:

- `user_a` : `/home/user_a/`
- `user_b` : `/home/user_b/`

`user_b` is in the group `user_a`

as `user_a`:

```
ls -ld /home/user_a/
drwxr-xr-x 10 user_a user_b 4096 Feb 28 11:49 /home/user_a/

ls -ld /home/user_a/foo/
drwxrwx--- 12 user_a user_a 4096 Feb 28 11:49 /home/user_a/foo/
```

Notice above the group of `foo/` is also `user_a`

as `user_b`:

```
cd /home/user_a/
cd foo/
Permission denied
```

According to my research, since `user_b` is in the group of dir `foo`, the group has `x` and `r` privileges, `user_b` should be able to cd to it. Why does `user_b` get permission denied?

Answer (score 0):

Had to log out and log in again as `user_b` before being a part of group `user_a` took effect.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion user_b is not in group user_a, and you get no permission denied, when you cd in the home of user_a, because it is in group user_b as one can see in your first ls.
I tried the same environment, user_a and user_b, user_b in group user_a, I can cd to every directory under user_a and even create files